# is there a way to 'sort' (remove) letters that are too much in a text?

Tags: sorting

Okay, hi everyone ! So i was wondering if there was some way to "sort" or remove letters that are too much. That's not very clear so here's an exemple :

If there is

> aaaaaabbbbbbccccccddddddeeeeeeffffffgggggghhhhhhiiiiiijjjjjjkkkkkkllllllmmmmmmnnnnnnooooooppppppqqqqqqrrrrrrssssssttttttuuuuuuvvvvvvwwwwwwxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz

can it just transform it to :

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

that would be very nice ! And if that could work for groups of letters also :

> APAAPAAPA

would be :

> APA

thanks ! I don't mind any OS (using linux for example).

Comment: What language are you using? Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Why does `APAAPAAPA` result in `APA`? I would expect either `AP` or `APAPAPA`?

Comment: Or is it recursively applied to groups? `APAAPAAPA -> A(PAA)(PAA)PA -> APAAPA -> AP(A)(A)PA -> APAPA -> A(PA)(PA) -> APA`?

Answer (score 0):

### Using a straightforward `for`-loop

You can iterate over the string and keep only characters which are not duplicates of the previous character. Here is an example code in C.

```c
void simplify(char *dest, char const *source)
{
    char previous_char = '\0';
    for (; *source; ++source)
    {
        if (*source != previous_char)
        {
            *dest = *source;
            previous_char = *source;
            ++dest;
        }
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}

#include <stdio.h>    /* printf */

int main(void)
{
    char source[] = "aaaaaabbbbbbccccccddddddeeeeeeffffffgggggghhhhhhiiiiiijjjjjjkkkkkkllllllmmmmmmnnnnnnooooooppppppqqqqqqrrrrrrssssssttttttuuuuuuvvvvvvwwwwwwxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz";
    char dest[200];

    simplify(dest, source);

    printf("Source: %s\nDest:   %s\n", source, dest);

    return 0;
}
```

### Using `groupby`

If your programming language already has libraries to process strings, you might not have to implement the iterating yourself. For instance, use `groupby` to group duplicate letters, then only keep one letter per group. Here is an example code in python:

```py
from itertools import groupby

def simplify(s):
  return ''.join(c for c,group in groupby(s))

source = "aaaaaabbbbbbccccccddddddeeeeeeffffffgggggghhhhhhiiiiiijjjjjjkkkkkkllllllmmmmmmnnnnnnooooooppppppqqqqqqrrrrrrssssssttttttuuuuuuvvvvvvwwwwwwxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz"

dest = simplify(source)

print('Source: {}\nDest:   {}\n'.format(source, dest))
```

What does `groupby` do? It groups adjacent elements according to a key. Here we didn't specify a key, so it groups identical adjacent elements. The result of `groupby('aaaaaabbbbbb...zzzzzz')` is something that looks like:

```
[('a', ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']),
 ('b', ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']),
 ...
 ('z', ['z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z'])]
```

where the first thing on each line is the "key", and then in the brackets we have the group of adjacent elements with that same key. In our case the key is the element itself, and we only want to keep one of each, so we just keep `c for c,group in groupby(s)`.